# How can I make emacs stop loading viper-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, viper-mode

I'm developing [a mode for Emacs](http://e2d73f83b6752f7f.paste.se/), and everytime I switch to its buffer, viper gets turned on. I've modified viper-mode to [trace](http://8e524f961b815d0a.paste.se/) where viper-mode is being called, and surprisingly *set-viper-state-in-major-mode* is called by running the *viper-post-command-hooks*, set to nil. Any idea of what is going on?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**: For the benefit of all beings, here is what I found out: as instructed by Trey, I started emacs with -Q and manually loaded both viper and my package. As I could reproduce the bug, the problem was on one of these packages. After line-by-line filtering, I discovered that the innoquous-looking (kill-all-local-variables) was causing the problem.

Comment: Have you added anything to the post-command-hook that might be triggering viper-mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's something in initialization that's causing it.

First try starting without your `.emacs` <kbd>emacs -q</kbd>.  If the problem persists, then the trigger is in the `site-start.el`.  So, talk to whomever installed Emacs and get them to remove the customizations there.  You can also always use the <kbd>-Q</kbd> startup option to avoid loading the `site-start.el`.

If the problem isn't in `site-start.el`, and you don't think it's in your `.emacs`, it might be in a custom `default.el` file, which you can prevent from being loaded by adding:

```
(setq inhibit-default-init t)
```

to your `.emacs`.

If you still have a problem, then I'm 99% sure it's in your .emacs.

To be 100% sure, try <kbd>emacs -Q</kbd>, which runs Emacs with no customizations.  If the problem persists, download and install your own Emacs b/c you surely can't trust the installation you're using.

So, now if you're convinced it's in your `.emacs`, start cutting out parts of your `.emacs`, or introduce an error in your `.emacs` with `(error "frog")`, and progressively rule out which portions of your `.emacs` are causing the problem.

g'luck

Answer (score 3):

The function `kill-all-local-variables` will run all functions added to `change-major-mode-hook`, this is a common way for *global* minor modes to initialize themselves. For example, *global font lock* and *global cwarn mode* use this.

I haven't used *viper* myself, but chances are that it use this mechanism. Of course, you still would have had to enable it in your init file, somehow, so if you simply would stop doing this, it would solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out any references to viper mode in your .emacs.  I don't get sent into viper mode, unless I start playing around with viper mode before I eval your new mode.

Maybe there's more being done with this statement than you think:

```
  (use-local-map ecoli-map)
```

Try to change some of your binds in your map.  eg. j to C-j and k to C-k.

Maybe emacs is getting confused?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your `~/.viper` config file, and also check your `.custom.el` for settings that might kick viper into action in your major mode (or globally).